# Center links in <li> menu vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have this menu:

```
<div id="menu">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="./index.html" target="_parent" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./programm.html" target="_parent">Programm & Preise</a></li>
        <li><a href="./kuenstler.html">Künstler</a></li>
        <li><a href="./rueckblick.html">Rückblick</a></li>
        <li><a href="./team.html" target="_parent">Team</a></li>
    </ul>

</div> <!-- end of menu -->
```

And this is the css I have at the moment:

```
/* menu */
#menu {
    clear: both;
    width: 670px;   
    height: 64px;
    background: url(images/menu_yellow.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

#menu ul li a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 94px;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;    
    font-weight: normal;
    outline: none;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JYsyCl6.png) repeat;
    opacity: .7;
}

#menu li a:hover, #menu li .current{
    color: #C30;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JYsyCl6.png) repeat;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The links are centered horizontally, but is it also possible to center it vertically inside the `<li>` that contain them?

I read about `vertical-align: middle ;` but just adding it to the links does not work.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkpfL/

Comment: Have you looked into [Flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `float: left;` so you won't need <s>`display: block;`</s>

So first, you don't need `display: block;` as when you `float`, even `inline` elements become floated blocks, as far as the vertical centering goes, instead of using `float`, use `display: table-cell;` along with `vertical-align: middle;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkpfL/10/)

```
#menu ul li a{
    display: table-cell; /* Add this */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Add this */
    width: 94px;
    height: 55px;
    padding-bottom: 5px; 
    /* Use this for a spare bottom space for your background-image */

    /* Rest of the properties goes here */
}
```

Also use `display: inline-block;` for the `li` element instead of `display: inline;` with `vertical-align: top;` *(Not required but better to be safe than sorry)*

```
#menu ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the second link is way higher then the others when I try it with your solution. Might be cause by the link using 2 lines instead of 1 like the others?

Comment: @whateverrest Yes, it's cuz of 2 lines, wait I'll do it

Comment: @whateverrest http://jsfiddle.net/gkpfL/9/ use `display: inline-block` for `li` instead of `display: inline`

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Why is there no horizontal align property ? How do we do a horizontal align ?

Comment: @HelloWorldNoMore sorry but what do you mean by horizontal align? Are you talking about `text-align: center;`

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Yes, like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can align them in the middle, but the arrow make them align lower than it should..you have to adjust it a little bit but it's something like:

```
#menu {
    clear: both;
    width: 670px;   
    height: 64px;
    background: url(images/menu_yellow.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

    #menu ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    #menu ul li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        display: table;
        background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JYsyCl6.png) repeat;
        width: 94px;
        height: 60px;
    }

    #menu ul li a{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;

        margin-right: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 13px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;    
        font-weight: normal;
        outline: none;

        opacity: .7;
    }

    #menu li a:hover, #menu li .current{
        color: #C30;
        background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JYsyCl6.png) repeat;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gkpfL/8/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/gkpfL/7/

changed the li to display:inline-block;

removed float:left; and added display:table-cell; and vertical-align:middle;

```
#menu ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu ul li a{
    width: 94px;
    height: 62px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;    
    font-weight: normal;
    outline: none;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JYsyCl6.png) repeat;
    opacity: .7;
     display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: `display: table-cell` with `display: inline-block`? Your `display: inline-block` isn't even affected, copy paste with caution :)

Comment: thanks @Mr.Alien, didn't see it, will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

An easy attemp would be to just replace the height with some padding

```
#menu ul li a{
 padding: 27.5px 0px;
 height: auto;
}
```

vertical-align works for inline/inline-block elements. Also you can center Content in Table cells with it. But it was not designed to center content liked this.

Comment: I get that you halved the height for padding - But what about the height of the text? Also, why should the left and right of the box also have padding?

Comment: @oGeez thank you :) i missed that i've given the padding for all directions. About the Text-size you are right as well. In this case you will have to set a certain line-height. Am i missing something?

Comment: Line-height won't help you, because there are occurrences where there is more than 1 line of text.

Comment: you could mess with the line-height of the `<li>` and set another line-height to the `a`... But like i said, it's a cheap workaround if you don't want to use something like display: table-cell for such a simple usecase.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YJjXC/)

```
/* menu */
#menu {
    clear: both;
    width: 670px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url(images/menu_yellow.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 94px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    outline: none;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JYsyCl6.png) repeat;
    opacity: .7;
}
#menu li a:hover, #menu li .current {
    color: #C30;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JYsyCl6.png) repeat;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[vertical-align](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align)

*The vertical-align property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element.*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS:

```
#menu {
    clear: both;
    width: 670px;   
height: 64px;
background: url(images/menu_yellow.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

#menu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: table-cell;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JYsyCl6.png) repeat;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 60px;
}

#menu ul li a{
float: left;
display: table-cell;
width: 94px;
padding: 7px 0 0 0;
margin-right: 5px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;    
font-weight: normal;
outline: none;
opacity: .7;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}

#menu lihover, #menu li.current{
color: #C30;
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/JYsyCl6.png) repeat;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Also you could think about creating the pointer with CSS using :after pseudo element